# Random NoTransaction in Pyramid

Tags: python, mysql, transactions, pyramid, waitress

I'm having trouble identifying the source of `transaction.interfaces.NoTransaction` errors within my Pyramid App. I don't see any patterns to when the error happens, so to me it's quite random.

This app is a (semi-) RESTful API and uses SQLAlchemy and MySQL. I'm currently running within a docker container that connects to an external (bare metal) MySQL instance on the same host OS.

Here's the stack trace for a login attempt within the App. This error happened right after another login attempt that was actually successful.

```
2020-06-15 03:57:18,982 DEBUG [txn.140501728405248:108][waitress-1] new transaction
2020-06-15 03:57:18,984 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:730][waitress-1] BEGIN (implicit)
2020-06-15 03:57:18,984 DEBUG [txn.140501728405248:576][waitress-1] abort
2020-06-15 03:57:18,985 ERROR [waitress:357][waitress-1] Exception while serving /auth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/waitress/channel.py", line 350, in service
    task.service()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/waitress/task.py", line 171, in service
    self.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/waitress/task.py", line 441, in execute
    app_iter = self.channel.server.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 270, in __call__
    response = self.execution_policy(environ, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyramid_retry/__init__.py", line 127, in retry_policy
    response = router.invoke_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 249, in invoke_request
    response = handle_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 178, in tm_tween
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyramid_tm/compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 135, in tm_tween
    userid = request.authenticated_userid
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyramid/security.py", line 381, in authenticated_userid
    return policy.authenticated_userid(self)
  File "/opt/REDACTED-api/REDACTED_api/auth/policy.py", line 208, in authenticated_userid
    result = self._authenticate(request)
  File "/opt/REDACTED-api/REDACTED_api/auth/policy.py", line 199, in _authenticate
    session = self._get_session_from_token(token)
  File "/opt/REDACTED-api/REDACTED_api/auth/policy.py", line 320, in _get_session_from_token
    session = service.get(session_id)
  File "/opt/REDACTED-api/REDACTED_api/service/__init__.py", line 122, in get
    entity = self.queryset.filter(self.Meta.model.id == entity_id).first()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3375, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3149, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3481, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3502, in _execute_and_instances
    conn = self._get_bind_args(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3517, in _get_bind_args
    return fn(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3496, in _connection_from_session
    conn = self.session.connection(**kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1138, in connection
    return self._connection_for_bind(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1146, in _connection_for_bind
    return self.transaction._connection_for_bind(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 458, in _connection_for_bind
    self.session.dispatch.after_begin(self.session, self, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 322, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zope/sqlalchemy/datamanager.py", line 268, in after_begin
    join_transaction(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zope/sqlalchemy/datamanager.py", line 233, in join_transaction
    DataManager(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zope/sqlalchemy/datamanager.py", line 89, in __init__
    transaction_manager.get().join(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transaction/_manager.py", line 91, in get
    raise NoTransaction()
transaction.interfaces.NoTransaction
```

The trace shows that the execution eventually reaches my project, but only my custom authentication policy. And it fails right where the database should be queried for the user.

What intrigues me here is the third line on the stack trace. It seems Waitress somehow aborted the transaction it created? Any clue why?

---

EDIT: Here's the code where that happens: `policy.py:320`

```py
def _get_session_from_token(self, token) -> UserSession:
    try:
        session_id, session_secret = self.parse_token(token)
    except InvalidToken as e:
        raise SessionNotFound(e)

    service = AuthService(self.dbsession, None)

    try:
        session = service.get(session_id)  # <---- Service Class called here 
    except NoResultsFound:
        raise SessionNotFound("Invalid session found Request headers. "
                              "Session id: %s".format(session_id))

    if not service.check_session(session, session_secret):
        raise SessionNotFound("Session signature does not match")

    now = datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC)
    if session.validity < now:
        raise SessionNotFound(
            "Current session ID {session_id} is expired".format(
                session_id=session.id
            )
        )

    return session
```

And here is an a view on the that service class method:

```py
class AuthService(ModelService):
    class Meta:
        model = UserSession
        queryset = Query(UserSession)
        search_fields = []
        order_fields = [UserSession.created_at.desc()]

    # These below are from the generic ModelClass father class
    def __init__(self, dbsession: Session, user_id: str):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.dbsession = dbsession
        self.Meta.queryset = self.Meta.queryset.with_session(dbsession)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("REDACTED")

    @property
    def queryset(self):
        return self.Meta.queryset

    def get(self, entity_id) -> Base:
        entity = self.queryset.filter(self.Meta.model.id == entity_id).first()

        if not entity:
            raise NoResultsFound(f"Could not find requested ID {entity_id}")
```

As you can see, the there's already some exception treatment. I really don't see what other exception I could try to catch on `AuthService.get`

Comment: The third line reflects the exception and stack trace that starts on the fourth line. `pyramid_tm` will roll back a transaction that cannot be completed. Working the stack trace from bottom to top, it appears the transaction gets rolled back because it cannot complete the `.join()` with a `None` object, which is obtained by the `self.queryset.filter(self.Meta.model.id == entity_id).first()`. So check the filter comparators and resultant query to ensure you get a record. Also `try` the query followed by an `except` to handle a failure early.

Comment: Thanks for replying @StevePiercy. I've edited the original question and added some code. I really don't see why the query returning `None` could cause an `Exception`. I think the trace points to this line exactly because it's the single point of database access. The issue happens when Zope tries to join the transaction, and can't find one. Could this be a misconfiguration of the Zope transaction manager?

Comment: It seems there's some silent exception being dealt with:
`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 178, in tm_tween    reraise(*exc_info)`. Checking on that file I can see:
`# an unhandled exception was propagated - we should abort the transaction and re-raise the original exception`. I'll try to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to be much simpler than tinkering inside Pyramid or SQLAlchemy.

Debugging my Authentication Policy closely, I found out that my it was **keeping a sticky reference for the `dbsession`**. It was stored on the first request ever who used it, and never released.

The first request works as expected, the following one fails: My understanding is that the object is still in memory while the app is running, and after the initial transaction is closed. The second request has a new connection, and a new transaction, but the object in memory still points to the previous one, that when used ultimately causes this.

What I don't understand is why the exception didn't happen *sometimes*. As I mentioned initially, it was seemingly random.

Another thing that I struggled with was in writing a test case to expose the issue. On my tests, the issue never happens because I have (and I've never seen it done differently) a single connection and a single transaction throughout the entire testing session, as opposed of a new connection/transaction per request, so I have not found no way to actually reproduce.

Please let me know if that makes sense, and if you can shed a light on how to expose the bug on a test case.

Comment: I suspect you only run into problems when running two requests at the same time which exposes some race conditions between the shared session being opened/closed in unexpected ways when each request is operating on it.

Comment: This system was not yet in production, and I was the only one with API keys to request it, so not really a concurrency issue. The root cause was really stale "transactoinless" sessions stored in memory.

If I waited long enough, they would eventually cause the "MySQL Gone" because the database server would time-out the connection. When reused before that, they would simply fail due to the lack of a transaction.